# Kendo UI Grid Failing with Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, mono, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have the following Grid.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Web.UI.ViewModels.CompanyViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {               
            columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add new company"))
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model => 
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
                model.Field(id => id.ID).DefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());
            })
            .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "Company"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "Company"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Company"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "Company"))
        )
    )
```

When I use this page what the application is hosted on a windows server, it loads and everything works great.

When I try access this page when the application is hosted on a Mono Server, then that page fails.

I managed to find at which point it is failing.

```
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
```

It tells me

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
```

The grid works if you just go

```
.Editable()
```

So it must be something to do with the pop-up feature.

Anyone have any idea why it would do this? I need to be able to edit the grid using the popup window, so just changing it to `.Editable()` is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With the `Solution Explorer` navigate to your reference to that file and right click it then open `Properties` then make sure that `Copy Local` is set to `True` I believe that will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not using Entity Framework. Mono does not ship with `System.Data.Entity` on `Ubuntu` / `Linux`. All My 3rd party packages have that property set to `true`. `System.Data.Entity` is part of EntityFramework.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk Oh ok didn't know you weren't using it, well I'm not too familiar with Mono but you should have some config file (I believe in Mono it is `system.web`) and in there you should see references to `System.Data.Entity`.  One should be in the `<configSections>` and 2 should be in `<entityFramework>` you should be able to remove both of those sections and everything should work.

Comment: I can confirm there is nothing in the the main `Web.config` or in the one in the `Views` folder. I also did a solution wide search for `System.Data.Entity` and nothing came up.